# Should I use \documentclass[12pt]{article} with \Large or \documentclass{article} with \LARGE?

Tags: fontsize, best-practices

So, I'm working on making some cards, and they need to have nice, large, clear text. So I've set the text to be \LARGE. Then I was thinking, am I doing bad things to the font by over-enlarging it? It seems the size options in `article` only go up to 12pt, but should I be using 12pt and \Large instead? That seems to be roughly equivalent.

Are either of these the right way to get very large text for printing cards and such, if that is the majority of the text in my document, or should I be defining the text as large somewhere else?

Comment: PDF is vector. Shrink paper size, print big! coming to a printer near you :P

Comment: With both of these options you should be getting a 17pt font size, right? You could also issue the commands `\fontsize{17}{20.5}\selectfont`, I suppose.

Comment: @percusse But fonts are designed to be printed at a specific size, and changes are made to the font when moving from 10pt to 12pt; it isn't just a rescale on a good font, there are actual changes.

Comment: sounded funnier before you dissected it , *sad face*

Comment: @percusse - Huh?

Comment: @Mico nevermind I failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10pt `\LARGE` is `\newcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{22}}`

12pt  `\Large` is  `\newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xviipt{22}}`

which is the same thing.

But for a custom font for a custom use like your card example, there is not a lot of point in restricting yourself to the sizes based on magstep scaling of the original cm fonts.

Add `\usepackage{fix-cm}` (if you are using cm) so your fonts are scalable and then just use

```
\fontsize{18}{25}\selectfont
```

or whatever fits best.

Comment: I'm not using CM. Is there an easy way to play with this for other fonts?

Comment: most other fonts are already available at any size so you can just use `\fontsize` as shown, no need for `fix-cm`