# On a Comment of Percusse: "Shrink Paper Size, Print Big!"

Tags: fontsize, scaling, books, landscape, book-design

In the post [Should I use \documentclass[12pt]{article} with \Large or \documentclass{article} with \LARGE?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147138/should-i-use-documentclass12ptarticle-with-large-or-documentclassarticle),

**Percusse made the following comment:**

*`PDF is vector. Shrink paper size, print big!`*

QUESTION: **Does this mean that if one geometrically reduces the paper size from say `paperwidth=5in and paperheight=8in` to, say, `paperwidth=4in and paperheight=6in`, `\footnotesize` will actually appear larger in the latter than it would in the former?**

I ask, because I have been working on a 4'' x 6'' book, in which `footnotesize`, in no way, appears to be too small; whereas, I suspect it would be far too small if the book were geometrically larger.

Are my eyes, perhaps, playing tricks on me? I have printed a couple of page sized by side an a landscape 8 1/2'' x 11'' piece of paper and the `footnote` fontsize seems fine to me---but I could very well be wrong.

For what it's worth, I have put together the following MWE which sets the default font size at 10pt and prints a few sentences with the default, with normalsize (which seems to be the deafault), and footnotesize (with a footnote)---the font sizes of which appear (roughly) to be the same.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=.3in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}

\textheight=5.25in 
\hoffset 10pt
\topmargin -65pt
\headheight 15pt 
\headsep 10pt 
\marginparwidth 35pt


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

This is a sentence. (default (10pt)) \\[15pt]

\normalsize
This is a sentence. (normalsize) \\[15pt]

\footnotesize
This is a sentence. (footnotesize)\footnote{This is a footnote.}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 15--16` :(

Comment: note as percusse commented later the first comment was intended mostly as a joke, but anyway if you are using fonts with optical scaling specifying a font that is twice the size is not the same as scaling the document later. One uses a 20pt font designed for headings one uses a 10pt font designed for text, enlarged. Either have their uses, it depends what the use is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comments; may I assume then that a 10pt font size, regardless of the geometrical size of the book, will always print the same size? And if so, then will `normalsize`, `large`, `Large`, and so forth, when used in conjunction with 10pt font size with *any* paper dimensions will always print the same as well?

Comment: well yes asuming you don't scale on printing. That is if you want a large-print book for children or accssibility or whatever, rather than use `\large` everywhere you can design for A6 and print (scaled x 2)  on A4, or for US paper design for 5"  but print on 10"  that was I believe the context of the old question asking about `\large`, But if you are designing on 5" to print unscaled at 5" then naturally you get the size you specify.

Comment: Many thanks @DavidCarlisle

Comment: The rule is simple: never do `\begin{document}\large`. The `memoir` class offers other sizes beyond the standard 10,11,12; with the `fontsize` package you can choose whatever base size you like.

Comment: Many thanks @egreg. I hope I remember that in the future; and thanks for pointing me  to the `memoir` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note as percusse commented later the first comment was intended mostly as a joke, but anyway if you are using fonts with optical scaling specifying a font that is twice the size is not the same as scaling the document later. One uses a 20pt font designed for headings one uses a 10pt font designed for text, enlarged. Either have their uses, it depends what the use is.

If you want a large-print book for children or accssibility or whatever, rather than use `\large` everywhere you can design for A6 and print (scaled x 2) on A4, or for US paper design for 5" but print on 10" that was I believe the context of the old question asking about `\large`, But if you are designing on 5" to print unscaled at 5" then naturally you get the size you specify.

Comment: Thank you David Carlisle.